# Accessing Elements of a Vector

Tags: java, vector, initialization

I want to put some integers into a Vector and to access them after that.
My code in Java Eclipse scrapbook looks like this:

```
java.util.Vector<> dp;
dp = new java.util.Vector(5);
dp.insertElementAt(new Integer(1));
dp.insertElementAt(new Integer(3));

for(int i =0; i< dp.size(); i++)
{

int lastint = ((Number) dp.lastElement()).intValue();
System.out.println("Element"  + lastint);

}
```

I get this error : "Incorrect number of arguments for type Vector; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>" but I did it like in the tutorial so I do not know why I get this.

Comment: 1. Don't use `Vector`. Use `ArrayList` instead.
2. You have to provide type parameters for the static type of a variable. You can leave them out elsewhere, but for variable declarations they are required.

Comment: `java.util.Vector<Integer> dp;`, also can you please tell us why are you using `Vector` instead of `ArrayList`?

Comment: "like in the tutorial" ..; which tutorial? the fact that it's still using Vector instead of an (Array)List tells me enough. 

try: Vector<Integer> dp instead of Vector<> dp

Comment: Some tutorials are *very old* or copies of ones which are.  Vectors was replaced by ArrayList in 1998 and calling `new Integer` was replaced by auto-boxing in 2004.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare type of the elements which you want to store in your Vector like that:

```
Vector<Integer> dp = new Vector<Integer>(5);
```

In Java 7 you can use Diamond syntax like this:

```
Vector<Integer> dp = new Vector<>(5);
```

but remember that `<>` syntax can be use only on the implementation not a reference.

By the way you shouldn't use `Vector` class at all it's obsolete.
You can use `ArrayList` if you don't need thread safety or `CopyOnWriteArrayList` (or `Collections.synchronizedList()`) if you need it.

Comment: Worth mentioning the existence of [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Vector is not obsolete (in the deprecated sense)!

Comment: I mean it shouldn't be use anymore, because it's been replaced by something better and word obsolete is ok to use in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
java.util.Vector<> dp;
```

With this one:

```
java.util.Vector<Integer> dp;
```

You cannot leave inside `<>` empty when defining a new variable. Compiler has to know which calss it is going to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Bunch of problems. You should write:

```
java.util.Vector<Integer> dp;
```

When you declare your vector. You can initialize with

```
dp = new java.util.Vector<>(5);
```

If you use Java 7 or more. Otherwise:

```
dp = new java.util.Vector<Integer>(5);
```

Also:

```
dp.insertElementAt(new Integer(1));
```

[insertElementAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#insertElementAt%28E,%20int%29) requires two arguments, the index at which to insert, and the actual value. But beware! You created the vector with a capacity of 5, not a size of 5. So anything other than *insertElementAt(someValue, 0)* will throw an *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException*. See the linked javadoc for the exact behavior.

Comment: I did it like you said and now I get Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would write it in Java 5.0 (2004) or later.

```
List<Integer> db = new ArrayList<Integer>();
db.add(1);
db.add(3);

for(int i : db)
    System.out.println("Element"  + i);
```

As you can see this much cleaner and since Java 7 (2011) you can write

```
List<Integer> db = new ArrayList<>();
```

> Incorrect number of arguments for type Vector; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>

This will happen if your IDE is set to Java 1.4 or older.  If you have a really old JDK (more than ten years old) you will also get this error.  Try to ensure you have a recent version of Java e.g. Java 8 update 5 and set your IDE to expect Java 8 code.

Comment: I like the way you solved this. I copied exactly the same code you posted here in my scrapbook and I get this error "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>"

Comment: @ClaudiusStephanusMaleficus Java 5.0 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 will compile this fine.  The problem will be your IDE which in some cases default to older versions.  If you don't have an IDE, the problem is you are running an older version than you think you are.